# Is it possible to inject a conditional class( based on a parameter from the previous fragment) into a view model?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm using Hilt.  I want to inject a subclass of `Foo` into my hilt view model.

All subclasses of `Foo` depend on different class that is already using an `@Inject` constructor and can be injected into view models, activities, etc. But not into my subclass, so I'm using `EntryPoints` to inject them.

Also, which subclass gets injected depends upon a property I'm getting from the previous fragment via the `SavedStateHandle` Hilt provides the view model.

Is it possible to create a Factory (or another solution) that somehow gets the param from the previous fragment and injects the correct Foo object?

I have a solution that doesn't use Hilt to get the `Foo` object, it just instantiates the right object using a conditional on the param.  This solution is not testable and I don't like it.

````
// in the view model I would like to do this
// 
// @Inject
// lateinit var thatFooINeed: Foo
//
// But thatFooINeed could be the Foo with Dependency1 or Dependency2
// It depends on the param sent from the previous fragment 


interface Foo {
  fun doThis() 
  fun doThat() 
}

class Bar1(context: Context): Foo {
  private val dependencyInterface = 
    EntryPoints.get(context, DependencyInterface::class.java)

    val dependency1: Dependency1 = dependencyInterface.getDependency1()

    // override doThis() and doThat() and use ^ dependency

    ...
}

class Bar2(context: Context): Foo {
  private val dependencyInterface = 
    EntryPoints.get(context, DependencyInterface::class.java)

    val dependency2: Dependency2 = dependencyInterface.getDependency2()

    // override doThis() and doThat() and use ^ dependency

    ...
}

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface DependenciesInterface {
    fun getDependency1(): Dependency1
    fun getDependency2(): Dependency2
}

class Dependency1 @Inject constructor(val yetAnotherDep: ButWhosCounting)

class Dependency2 @Inject constructor(val yetAnotherDep: ButWhosCounting)```
````

Comment: I'm completely open to the possibility that my architecture sucks and I need to refactor.

Comment: Check this documentation about interface injection https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to adopt `@AssistedInject`, assisted injection will work as factory for your case. Inject the factory and then use the factory to lazily create the instance of the interface.